# Gedit adds line at end of file

Tags: text-editor, whitespace, gedit

The answer to this must be somewhere but I'm not finding it -- can anyone help me understand why in Gedit, if I have a page of code there is no extra trailing blank line, but then when I do a file comparison for my svn commit it shows an extra line being added at the end of the file?

I have a feeling that Gedit is automatically adding an ending line break. But why, I have no idea...

Comment: Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/379367

Comment: It's annoying that Gedit also *saves* after adding the newline, even without asking it to save.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Reality finally won and it's been [fixed](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625955), but the broken behavior is still the default; enable the WYSIWYG behavior in a terminal with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor ensure-trailing-newline false
```

Comment: Ugh, ensure-trailing-newline instead of hide-and-ensure-trailing-newline aaargh

Comment: In case you see the `dconf-WARNING **: 01:23:35.210: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)` error then (for `debian` and its friends) run the `apt install dbus-x11` command first

Comment: ... also, looks like this solution doesn't work for ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 6):

It's a [feature](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=526612). I don't think it can easily be disabled.

> this is intentional: text files should always be terminated by \n, otherwise
>   tools like 'cat', 'sed' etc may have problems. However there is no reason to
>   always show an empty line at the bottom of the text view, that's why we do not
>   show the last \n
>
> paolo borelli   [gedit developer]

Comment: Thanks. This is unfortunate because I wanted to use gedit but I need to be able to delete that line break in some cases... I wonder if that's possible.

Comment: I would like to see a small space at the bottom (even a single pixel) so I can more easily tell the difference between an underscore and a space.

Comment: Feature or not, it's absolutely misleading and counter-intuitive to change file contents without making it visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Some editors (I'm unfamiliar with Gedit specifically) will try to ensure that a file *always* ends with a newline character. Other editors, like perhaps the one that you originally created the file with, will allow you to end a file *without* a final newline character.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Whitespace Remover](https://github.com/dinkel/gedit-whitespace-remover/) plugin.