# FileReader always read at least one newline despite none in file in Java

Tags: java, file, filereader

I have this code...

```
try{
    FileReader fread = new FileReader(new File("testfile"));
    int y = 0;
    while (fread.ready()){
        char path = (char)fread.read();
        System.out.println(path);
        if (path == '\n'){
            y++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Newlines: " + y);
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

...and a file called testfile containing the following information...

```
ABC
```

...and when I run the program it prints out that the file contains one newline. Why is that? I simply cannot find the reason why, having read the Oracle documentation. My problem is easily solved by subtracting one from y, but I am not satisfied with that. This problem drives me crazy since I have no clue where the newline comes from.

Comment: Are you sure about the contents of the file? How did you generate it? Does it have length 3 or 4?

Comment: The files was created this way.
1. Pressing "ABC".
2. Saving.
3. Exiting.

Comment: With which editor? Most editors will put a line end after each line. On which OS are you? can you make a hexdump of the file and check?

Comment: I am using gedit on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Thank you, the editor was adding invisible newlines after the eof. I disabled it with the following command for gedit: gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor ensure-trailing-newline false

Comment: Side note: don' use ready(). It doesn't do what you think it does. Just read until read() returns -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

My editor (and several else) was adding a newline after eof in the file. Here are pages that list different solutions for different editors:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/13317/how-to-stop-gedit-gvim-vim-nano-from-adding-end-of-file-newline-char

[Gedit adds line at end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056740/gedit-adds-line-at-end-of-file)